# Using the field calculator to copy one column's values to another's BLANK values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, copy

This is probably a basic and simple question which has been answered multiple times before, but my Google-fu has come up empty, so here we are.

Long story short, to simplify my analysis, I want to copy the data from the first zoning column field to the second into ONLY in cell values which are blank. I will attach a screenshot to show what I am talking about.

I have tried various [case when] and [if] examples, but nothing seems to get this thing to go.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a layer, in which some values in a field are blank, enter the following in **Field Calculator** and select **Update Existing Field**, zone_2:

```
if("zone_2" is null, "zone_1", "zone_2")
```

Alternatively, if the fields are simply blank rather than NULL, enter the following:

```
if( "zone_2" = '', "zone_1", "zone_2")
```

The result is the same, as shown below.

Before:

[image: table prior to update, with nulls]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your conditionnal test doesn't work you can also select the "right" features and update **only those selected** (there should be a checkbox to limit the changes) ...

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks. Yeah, I pretty much did this. I did a select by expression, then at the top of the attribute table I selected [overlay] and put in "zonedist" and clicked update selected.

If someone wants to show how to do this with the field calculator though, I am all for learning new things :)